# Filter array of object in AngularJs UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In AngularJS UI Grid, I receive JSON object and bind it to a grid. Now I want to filter rows based on multiple conditions from some checkboxes.

For example, I have 3 checkboxes for time:

```
10:00 - 12:00 -- checkbox
14:00 - 18:00 -- checkbox
20:00 - 23:00 -- checkbox
```

If the user clicks on the `10:00 - 12:00` and `14:00 - 18:00` checkboxes, the row should filtered based on those times.

```
$scope.filterGrid = function(value) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].rows.entity.length(); i++) {
        // I put one condition here as an example, but in my code all of the conditions
        // are included
        if ($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].rows.entity[i].time >= "14:00" &&
            $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].rows.entity[i].time <= "18:00") {
                $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters[0]={term:value};
        }
    }
};
```

In my code, I can get what the object contains in the time ranges, but when I add objects into the grid, I only ever get last added object.  For example, if I have 4 objects, the grid always show the 4th object.

I think rather than adding objects, I am overwriting them.  How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i think you try to compare if a date is smaller or equal than a string. afaik this is not possible

Comment: i get data,my problem is when i bind n object with $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters[0]={term:value}; grid always show last object

Comment: can you try to use `$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters.add({term:value});`? you assign all elements that match your if-clause to be the first of the list, therefore always overriding the previous value. I would guess that the length of your list is 1.

Comment: You may try $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters.push({term:value})

Comment: Sorry, I meant push (was to long in the java world)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change:

```
    $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters[0]={term:value};
```

to:

```
    $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filters[i]={term:value};
```